# Why does nothing shows up ( only a black screen ) on my laptop startup?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 19.04

My laptop is an Asus x510u, i5 8th gen CPU.

Problem: When I press the power button the button glows and the laptop turns on, but nothing is displayed on the screen and screen remains black. I have 3 OS installed - Ubuntu, Windows 10, and Phoenix OS (it's an android x86_64 OS). While having a black screen I can navigate ( by intuition ) and select Phoenix OS and it runs and displays phoenix OS logo after some time (almost instantly). But if I select another OS the screen remains black.

Also, I tried to access the bios, but I can't because the screen remains black. I can play games like PubG mobile in Phoenix OS as well.

Please help, my laptop is under warranty but I want to solve it because it will take time in the service centre.

I used HDMI cable then I get my display on the other monitor. It works absolutely fine in the external monitor but there is still no display on my monitor. Note: I don't think that my laptop's monitor is faulty as I can run phoenix os perfectly.

Note: I removed phoenix os and now I can successfully boot to ubuntu, but I still can't view my bios and windows.

o/p of command from ubuntu: `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. UHD Graphics 620
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GP108M [GeForce MX150]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: This will sound stupid which is why I'm adding it as a comment and not an answer but: If possible remove the battery, and unplug power. Hold the power button down for a good amount of time (30-60 seconds) to ensure all capacitors are discharged, then stick the battery back in and try again. I suggest this silliness because I've had a couple similar issues on my desktop and the only way I've been able to get the graphics card to take off again is by killing all power to the motherboard and restarting. In my case I could get Windows to display, but not Linux. My problem was with 18.04.2 LTS